# Finding Second Order Derivatives

Tags: partial-derivative, chain-rule

To obtain d'Alembert's soltion to the wave equation:
$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial t^2}=\alpha^2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2} $$
Change of variables is used: $\psi=x+at$, $\eta=x-at$.
Then chain rule can be applied to find the first order partial derivatave of $u$: $$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \psi}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}$$
But I don't understand how the second order partial derivative can be expressed into this form:$$\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \psi^2}+2\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \psi\partial \eta}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \eta^2}$$
In particular, 
$$ \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial \psi}=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \psi^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \psi\partial \eta}$$
Can someone please explain explain how the calculation is carried out? I refer to Thomas Calculus but there is no where inside the book can explain the second order partial differentiation.

P/S: I found this on physics forum:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial }{\partial s}\right)$$
$$\frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}}=\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial }{\partial s}\right)\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial }{\partial s}\right)$$
Why does the partial derivative act somehow like polynomial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial \psi}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\psi}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right]=\frac{\partial}{\partial\psi}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial \psi}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\right]=\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \psi^2}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial \psi\partial \eta}\ ,
$$
where one uses the first derivative you had computed earlier
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial \psi}+\frac{\partial u}{\partial \eta}\ .
$$

Comment: Is it always true that $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial \psi}=\frac{\partial}{\partial\psi}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right]$?

Comment: @Dave Clifford What is *always* true is $\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x\partial \psi}=\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial \psi}\right]$ [as this is just the definition of a mixed second derivative]. If then this (mixed) second derivative is everywhere continuous in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then this is also equal to $\frac{\partial}{\partial\psi}\left[\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}\right]$ by Schwarz' theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_of_second_derivatives